# Is there any alternative for CCMoveBy Action in cocos2d in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Is there any alternative for CCMoveBy Action in cocos2d in iphone ??

If anybody know about this.. plz reply.

Comment: Can you explain why you need an alternative? Why doesnt CCMoveBy fit your need?

Comment: Am implementing a car game. I am moving car by using CCMoveBy. I have to restrict my car inside the track (road). So, every time if car collides with the edges of the road, then I have to stop the CCMoveBy action manually. 

So, suggest me an alternative by applying which I don’t have to stop the car manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to using actions to move sprites is to use simple physics. You can extend the CCSprite class to include an update method as well as ivars / properties to keep track of x and y velocity.

In the update method, move the sprite by velocity * dT in each direction.
Call the sprites update method in the update method of your game scene.

MovingSprite.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
@interface MovingSprite : CCSprite {
    float _vx;
    float _vy;
}

-(void) update:(ccTime)dt;

@property (nonatomic, assign) float vx;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float vy;

@end
```

MovingSprite.m

```
#import "MovingSprite.h"

@implementation MovingSprite

@synthesize vx = _vx;
@synthesize vy = _vy;

-(void)update:(ccTime)dT
{
    self.vy -= (kGravity * dT); //optionally apply gravity
    self.position = ccp(self.position.x + (self.vx*dT), self.position.y + (self.vy*dT));
}
```

And add `[self scheduleUpdate];` to the init method of your game layer. Then add an update method within the game layer where you call update for all moving sprites.

Now you just need to add collision detection to check if the car collides with the sides of the track.